# Enlazar variable del html al typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Este es mi componente:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-pages',
  styleUrls: ['pages.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <ngx-one-column-layout>
      <nb-menu [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </ngx-one-column-layout>
  `,
})
export class PagesComponent {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    console.log(this.translate.instant('adminPanel'));
  }

  menu = MENU_ITEMS;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    MENU_ITEMS[0]["title"]= this.translate.instant('adminPanel');
    this.menu = MENU_ITEMS;
  }
}
```

Funciona todo bien pero el cambio de variable de "menu" cuando la sobrescribo no se cambia en el html hasta que no salgo de la página y vuelvo a entrar, lo que me indica que se cambia tarde y no admite el cambio de forma dinámica.
He intentado asignar un EventEmitter al nb-menu, pero no puedo ya que no puedo entrar a nb-menu para modificarlo desde dentro ya que es una etiqueta de nebular (un framework que me he bajado)

Comment: no hay evento,    la sobrescribo aquí -->  this.menu = MENU_ITEMS;

Comment: Ya lo se ya... xD no puedo hacerlo de otra forma

Answer (score 0):

Y si este codigo:

```
 this.menu = MENU_ITEMS;
```

Lo ejecutas en el [ngAfterViewChecked()](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview), en vez del ngOnInit(), eso podría funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto, en la documentación de [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) especifica claramente que el método instant es sincrono y el cargador de archivos predeterminado es asíncrono.

Y por lo que quieres desarrollar es mejor usar el método get ya que te devuelve un Observable.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-pages',
  styleUrls: ['pages.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <ngx-one-column-layout>
      <nb-menu [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </ngx-one-column-layout>
  `,
})
export class PagesComponent {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    console.log(this.translate.instant('adminPanel'));
  }

  menu = MENU_ITEMS;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.translate.get('adminPanel')
      .subscribe(trl => this.menu[0]['title'] = trl)
  }
}
```

Espero que te sirva de algo este aporte, Un saludo.